# Spring Neo4j: unable to save node with id

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

So i'm trying to create then delete a node in Neo4j with spring

```
@Data
@NodeEntity
public class Tweet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    @Relationship(type = "POST", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Person person;
}

@Repository
public interface TweetRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Tweet, Long> {}

@Test
public void testCreateDelete() {
    Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
    tweet.setId(123L);
    tweet.setText("example");
    tweetRepository.save(tweet);
    Optional<Tweet> dbTweet = tweetRepository.findById(tweet.getId());
    if (!dbTweet.isPresent()) fail("save failed");
    tweetRepository.deleteById(tweet.getId());
    dbTweet = tweetRepository.findById(tweet.getId());
    if (dbTweet.isPresent()) fail("delete failed");
}
```

The problem is, this unit test will fail if i call tweet.setId(...) [save failed], and success if i comment it. I really need to set id field to avoid duplication data. Is it forbidden to set id field by ourself? If so, is there any efficient way i can ensure that the data is still unique? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The id field reflects the underlying Neo4j graphId of a node or relationship, and the field is never under user control. If you want to look up a node consistently, use a different field for the identifier and create an index for the label/property for fast lookup.

As far as uniqueness, you can create a uniqueness constraint on the label/property, and if you want some autogenerated ID then you might look to [Graphaware's uuid plugin](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid).